# How to stop a division if the result is a float number?

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point, integer

i have programmed this code but it show me partially the result as example 50/3 show me 16 while i want to introduce to stop this kind of operations if float. How to do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int number, divisor, x, y;
    printf("Enter the Natural Number to find Divisors\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Enter the Natural Number to divide for\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
        
    printf("Divisors of the number %d are \n", number);
    y=number/x;
    for (divisor = 1; divisor<=number;divisor++){
    if((number%divisor)==0){
    printf("%d\n", divisor);
    
    }
    else{
    continue; }
    
}
printf("The result of the division is %d", y);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `J` is a variable with a fixed type, defined *in your program*. So there is nothing to analyze. If you are looking to check if `x` is divisible by `i`, it would be another question (with a simple answer).

Comment: The part of x Is working, the division worked till i didn't change the settings of j. I Just wanted to show only the integer while It cutted the float and show me the results

Comment: The condition `if("J=%d")` is testing whether the pointer to the string `"J=%d"` is null — and it isn't.  It is not clear exactly what you want to test — maybe `if (j == x / i)`, but there are type issues to deal with here.

Comment: I want just test if a specific division gives the remainder in full or as a float and show only the integer.

Comment: `if("J=%d")` is complete nonsense, with or without the quotes, even with the same lowercase of `j`. It looks like vague guesswork of how the language works. But before then `j=x/i;` is dividing by `0`.

Comment: There is an operator in C that gives the remainder. There is an operator that gives a result of integer division.

Comment: What is the type of `x` and `j`?  Are you aware of the modulus operator, `%`, where (given two integers `p` and `q`) `p % q` returns the remainder when `p` is divided by `q`?  Note that if `x` is an `int`, the division in `j = x / i;` is done as integer division, yielding an integer result that is then converted to the corresponding `float` value (since you say `j` is a `float`).  This sort of gotcha is why it is helpful to provide an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses).

Comment: I am sorry, due to my bad english i cannot understand your answers but for what i translated they are far from my problem

Comment: I edited with the entire code, which should explain much more then before. This code is created for show the number of divisions possible and show the result of the division i wanted to. As example, all the divisions of X=10 for Y=2, and so on the other divisions, but show me only the integer results and count them

Comment: There are no example of what i am doing in the web.

Comment: I solved it thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how far I have to read your code:

```
for (i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    j=x/i;
```

What do you think a division by 0 should do?

But lets keep going:

```
if("J=%d")
```

This tests if the string constant is NULL, which can never be.

Overall it looks like you are trying to test if `x` is a prime. In that case you need to start the loop at `2` and test the remainder:

```
if (x % i == 0)
```

Comment: No is not a way to test if x is a prime, is a way to count the number of divisions done during a division.

Comment: same `if` test for both cases

Comment: I edited with the entire code, which should explain much more then before. This code is created for show the number of divisions possible and show the result of the division i wanted to. As example, all the divisions of X=10 for Y=2, and so on the other divisions, but show me only the integer results and count them

Comment: You didn't apply any of the fixes mentions here or in the comments.

Comment: I don't see any of the fixes mentions you wrote.

Comment: @Deanjoe Start the loop at 2, use `%`.

Comment: I tried but it not helped me, it started shown the number of memory i think, located for the number of time counted in i.

Comment: What is the name of this operation x % i == 0?  How to look up in the web for this?

Comment: I solved it, thanks for all.